# unique_ptr with forward declared incomplete type won't compile

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, incomplete-type

I am trying to follow the PIMPL idiom for C++. I have thus created a class `AgeDetect` which will be my user facing interface, and `AgeDetectImpl` which contains all the implementation. I am forward declaring `AgeDetectImpl` and using an `std::unique_ptr` to store it as a private member of `AgeDetect`. I followed the instructions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954518/stdunique-ptr-with-an-incomplete-type-wont-compile) question and have implemented a destructor so I am not sure what the issue is.

`AgeDetect.h`

```
#ifndef AGE_DETECT_H
#define AGE_DETECT_H

#include <memory>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

class AgeDetect {
    class AgeDetectImpl;
    std::unique_ptr<AgeDetectImpl> m_ageDetectImplPtr = nullptr;
public:
    AgeDetect(std::string token);
    ~AgeDetect();

    std::string getAge(std::string imagepath);
    std::string getAge(uint8_t* buffer, size_t rows, size_t cols);
    std::string getAge(const cv::Mat& image);
};


#endif
```

`AgeDetect.cpp`

```
#include "ageDetect.h"
#include "ageDetectImpl.h"

AgeDetect::~AgeDetect() = default;

AgeDetect::AgeDetect(std::string token) {
    //m_ageDetectImplPtr = std::make_unique<AgeDetectImpl>(token);
    }
```

Error Message

```
 error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘AgeDetect::AgeDetectImpl’
  static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,
```

**Edit**
Fixed header guards

Comment: You need a pimpl deleter:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954518

Comment: Also, your header guard `__AGE_DETECT_H__` is a reserved identifier because it has two underscores in it, also because it starts with an underscore at the global (preprocessor) scope.

Comment: @Eljay can you elaborate more on what a pimpl deleter is? From that thread, it looks like my wrapper class needs to have a deleted, which mine does `~AgeDetect();`

Comment: @Eljay and thank you for the info about the header guard, I fixed that

Comment: Can it be the assignment to nullptr at the beginning? No easy access to a compiler at the moment

Comment: Can you guys explain why initializing it to `nullptr` is an issue?

Comment: Look at the answer that duplicates this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850629/unique-ptr-pimpl-forward-declaration-and-complete-definition In particular the section "Why is the complete type required?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by CuriouslyRecurringThoughts and Jarod42, the issue was due to the assignment of `nullptr` to `m_ageDetectImplPtr`

The following code works

```
    class AgeDetectImpl;
    class AgeDetect {
    public:
        AgeDetect(std::string token);
        ~AgeDetect();

        std::string getAge(std::string imagepath);
        std::string getAge(uint8_t* buffer, size_t rows, size_t cols);
        std::string getAge(const cv::Mat& image);

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<AgeDetectImpl> m_ageDetectImplPtr;
    };
```