# In what situation does it make sense to forward declare a class within a class in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

I recently came across the following pattern:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void update() = 0;
    class B;
};

class A::B : public A {
public:
    virtual void update() {}
};
```

Here, B is exposed externally to be overridden.

My question is why would it make sense to define a derived class as a forward declaration that inherits from the base, rather than just creating a separate class and overriding the update function?

This seems to introduce unnecessary coupling.

Comment: `class B` within class `A` does not declare a data member.   It declares, but does not define, a nested class named `A::B`.   Your example then defines that class.   That said, it's not obvious to me what the purpose of defining a class `A::B` that is derived from `A` would be.   Try asking the developer who has used such an approach.    Using a forward declaration (of the class `B` within `A`) is a common approach for declaring a class without defining it - since a class declaration is sufficient to *declare* (not define) functions that work with pointers or references to such classes.

Comment: As already mentioned above, this has nothing to do with data. The `A::B` can be used in a type trait “pattern” in contexts where `A` is a template argument and there are perhaps classes other than `A`, each of which defines their own `B`. In STL you can frequently see this as (e.g.) the `::iterator` type inside container types or as `::type` in (pure) type trait classes. As for “in what situation”, I’d say it makes a lot of sense when combined with templates. Without templates, not really sure; in that case `A` serves as a kind of a “namespace” for `B`, but doesn’t really do much otherwise.

Comment: I suspect the answer will depend on the actual names of the classes and/or If there's a factory function in `A`. I can see some organizational and stylistic points for this in those cases.

Comment: *"This seems to introduce unnecessary coupling."* The coupling might be intended, as pimpl, iterator, node, ...

Comment: You can't determine whether the coupling is unnecessary by studying the construct in isolation. Look to the surrounding code for motivation.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring, or a forward declaration, of a class in class doesn’t make it a member, it creates something akin to a namespace. Often it is declared privately so its use is internal to the class it is declared in. A derivation creates a tight coupling.

*Common examples of use of a class within a class*

One common such use is in the implementation of the [`pimpl` idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25850629/3747990).

Typically it is only a forward declaration, and the definition is then in a separate cpp file, thus hiding the implementation.

Reasons to hide the implementation vary;

- keeping code secret
- compiler firewalls
- bringing down partial rebuild/compile time

> This seems to introduce unnecessary coupling. A class within a class for derived use

Your example may be complicating this, but the devil is in the detail, more context on any factories or intent from class names may offer more specific insight to your code sample. An upshot though is that the compiler can check that new pure virtual functions are implemented in the pimpl.

To the question;

> My question is why would it make sense to define a derived class as a forward declaration that inherits from the base, rather than just creating a separate class and overriding the update function?

There may not be a lot of sense, it would be highly specific to the situation, and short of more details, the general use cases above are a good place to start.

Comment: Given this answer, I'm noticing that the question in the title isn't quite the same question as the question in the body.  This may be a question about inheritance.

Comment: What you describe is relevant to the question of declaring (nesting) a class within a class.   However, the pimpl (in sense of the pimpl idiom) is often [I'd even suggest usually] not derived from its containing class, which is part of the OP's example.

Comment: @peter, sure, there is a lot of detail missing in the sample. The question needs more detail for a more specific answer

Answer (score -1):

If the premise is to have `B` nested in `A` (for nested classes there are special rules for eg name lookup and access that might be relevant, see below for an example) then you do need the forward declaration because you cannot inherit from an incomplete type:

```
class C {
    public:
        class B : public C {

        };
};
```

[causes the compiler error](https://godbolt.org/z/r659ohnM3):

```
<source>:3:26: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class C'
    3 |         class B : public C {
      |                          ^
<source>:1:7: note: definition of 'class C' is not complete until the closing brace
    1 | class C {
      |       ^
```

---

This is an example that allows the derived class to access a member of the enclosing class even though it is `private`:

```
class C {
    private: 
       int x;
    public:
        class B;
};

class C::B : public C {
    void foo() { x = 42; }
};
```

(Though, I find the rules for nested classes so unintuitive and unexpected that I usually avoid them.)

---

> This seems to introduce unnecessary coupling.

In your example it seem unnecessary indeed. Though the design might be motivated by parts you left out from your example.